# Split Column in 3 columns with R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to separate a column into 3 columns.
My code:

```
   library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
table1 <- read.csv("tablepartipants.csv")
table2 <- tidyr::separate(table1, col = unique_participant, into = c("uID", "gender", "employment"), sep='.')
```

I always get this error: Expected 3 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 80 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].

[This is how the column dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJ07.png)

All 3 "new" columns are empty...

Comment: you can also try `data.table::tstrsplit()`

Comment: Could you try with `sep = "\."`? From the help-file: *If character, is interpreted as a regular expression. The default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values.*. A dot mathes every character in regex ....

Comment: Furthermore: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `sep` part of your command. A period is the default and `.` is a special character.

```
# Example data.frame
table1 <- data.frame(unique_participant = paste0(30:33, c('.male.Student', '.female.Student')))
```

One option

```
separate(table1, unique_participant, into = c("uID", "gender", "employment"))
```

Or using `\\.` to specify a period.

```
separate(table1, unique_participant, into = c("uID", "gender", "employment"), sep = '\\.')
```